# capturing output in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a need to capture all the rendered output/html of a view so that I can persist the result.  How can I do this within ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I think you need to write an httpmodule, but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm aware of that solution. I'm just curious to see if there's another place to hook into the mvc stack to capture the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great post about partial output caching and includes code about how to capture output using an attribute.

The post: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/10/15/partial-output-caching-in-aspnet-mvc/
The code: http://blog.codeville.net/blogfiles/2008/October/ActionOutputCacheAttribute.cs

Answer (score 0):

MVC Views output to the response stream via an HtmlTextWriter object in the HttpContext. So, one way to accomplish your task is to replace the existing HttpContext object with a new which contains an HtmlTextWriter that is outputting to a StringBuilder rather than the response stream.

This is reasonably straightforward if a little complicated and is covered in some detail in this blog post: http://andrewlocatelliwoodcock.com/2011/04/28/capturing-the-output-of-a-view-as-a-string/

I have used this technique successfully to capture View output as it is sent to the browser.

Don't forget: if you want to actually see the View as well, once you have captured the output you will also need to write it to the response stream ...